# what does "-session ..." mean in /etc/pam.d/system-session?

Tags: linux, pam, systemd

In Red Hat 7 I see

```
-session   optional    pam_systemd.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/system-session`.

I also see that the `-` prefix is mentioned in LFS docs:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6-systemd/general/systemd.html

Please help me understand what does `-session` means here as opposed to simple `session`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing `man pam.conf`:

```
   If the type value from the list above is prepended with a -
   character the PAM library will not log to the system log if it
   is not possible to load the module because it is missing in the
   system. This can be useful especially for modules which are not
   always installed on the system and are not required for correct
   authentication and authorization of the login session.
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. I have been there, but completely overlooked this section.

Comment: Exactly same situation here lol :)